# What is Schema @id and does inaccessible URLS within it matter?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, local-seo, google-rich-snippets-tool, google-local-search

I am in the process of installing Schema on my friends website. I'm adding [ServiceType](https://schema.org/serviceType) to his [House Clearance](http://gogreendorset.co.uk/services/house-clearance-bournemouth/) page, as well as all his other services that he provides to the local area of Bournemouth using `areaServed > GeoShape > circle`, which is still in development.

*Since the website is powered by WordPress the code within the loop looks like this:*

```
<?php ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service">
    <?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

*WordPress the_ID*

If your not familiar with WordPress `id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"` appends the unique page id to the element. As you can see from the code above both the `id="post-X"` and `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service"`are attached to the element container `<article>`.

*Using [Google's Rich Snippet Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fgogreendorset.co.uk%2Fservices%2Fhouse-clearance%2F) I get the following results:*

[image: serviceType House Clearance]

As you can see @id is taking the ID from the element and appending it to the path of the page without a HASHTAG, meaning that URL doesn't actually exist and returns a 404 status.

*Question(s):*

- What is the purpose of Schema @id?
- Does it matter if that URL is accessible or not?
- Should I rename `id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"` to `class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"` or add a new line with serviceType?

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a (long-standing) bug in Google’s SDTT.

Relevant Stack Overflow question:
[*Why does Google Testing Tool use the “id” attribute to generate a URL for the Microdata item?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491507/why-does-google-testing-tool-use-the-id-attribute-to-generate-a-url-for-the-mi)

In Microdata, only the **`itemid` attribute** should be able to give a URI for the item, while the **`id` attribute** is only used for referencing elements on the same page (with the `itemref` attribute), not for providing URIs. So the SDTT should never do anything with `id` values after following all `itemref` references.

If you provide a value for the `itemid` attribute, it overwrites the value the SDTT extracts from the `id` attribute. That would be the only way to fix this problem from our side.

```html
<article id="post-29" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Service" itemid="/acme-service#this">
```

The `itemid` attribute takes a URI as value. It’s a good practice to offer a relevant document under this URI, but it’s not required by Microdata. `itemid` serves the [same purpose as `@id` in JSON-LD](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) and `resource` in RDFa Lite.