# When a WebPage (or similar type) uses an ID that matches a breadcrumb ID, why does the WebPage become part of the BreadcrumbList?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, breadcrumbs, webpage

Is this what is supposed to happen? If so, why?

Here's an example ([test code here](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "http://example.com/"
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":{
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":{
    "@id": "http://example.com/",
    "name": "Lecture 12: Graphs, networks, incidence matrices"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think it makes sense that Google’s SDTT does this. It’s just a usability question if the `WebPage` item should be displayed as top-level item in addition; it doesn’t affect the semantics.

In the first `script` data block, you say that the `WebPage` has the URI `http://example.com/`. In the second `script` data block, you say that the value of the `item` property has the same URI, `http://example.com/`.
Because these two items have the same URI, they have to be the same thing.

You may want to use the [`breadcrumb` property](http://schema.org/breadcrumb) to make clear that the `BreadcrumbList` belongs to the `WebPage`:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "WebPage",
 "@id": "http://example.com/",
 "breadcrumb": {
   "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
   "itemListElement":{
     "@type": "ListItem",
     "position": 1,
     "item":{
      "@id": "http://example.com/",
      "name": "Lecture 12: Graphs, networks, incidence matrices"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see in the SDTT, the properties you provide for the `item` property will be displayed under the top-level `WebPage` item.

(N.B.: Google’s SDTT seems to be bugged for cases where different types get provided for the same URI.)

Comment: "You may want to use the breadcrumb property to make clear that the BreadcrumbList belongs to the WebPage." That seems to make the most sense. What would you recommend for [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) types? The top level item really doesn't matter?

Comment: @JohnRPerry: Personally (because I like to be expressive with my structured data) I always use a `WebPage` type; if it’s a page with a single `Article`, I have: `ItemPage mainEntity Article` and `ItemPage breadcrumb BreadcrumbList`. -- Regarding top-level items: From the perspective of Schema.org, it doesn’t matter. I think there was a time when Google only displayed Rich Snippets for top-level items, but I think this is no longer the case (I’m not sure though, as I don’t care about it).

Comment: Last question: I never really paid attention to the URI because schema.org doesn't really include it in their example markup, but it seems to function like a canonical tag. Do you use it in your own work?

Comment: @JohnRPerry: That topic is somewhat complex (and Schema.org decided to omit it in their examples/documentation because of this). In short: If you want to follow best practices of the Semantic Web / Linked Data, you should use the canonical URI of the page only for the `WebPage` item, and a different URI for the thing that gets described on the page. Details: [example what Apple does](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) ·· [explanation why/how to differentiate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669).

Comment: Okay thank you very much. Sorry one more final question, I promise: if you're adding markup to a blog post and `ItemPage` is the top-level and `Article` is the `mainEntity` does `Article` or `ItemPage` get the `name`, `url`, `description`, etc. *If this should be asked as a unique question entirely, let me know.*

Answer (score 1):

Think of ID as a global variable, the first time you "declare" its value, this value is set througout the document and will "render" the given value anywhere you call the ID.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "http://example.com/" *here you give ID a value*
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":{
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":{
    "@id": "http://example.com/", *here you just "paste" the given value*
    "name": "Lecture 12: Graphs, networks, incidence matrices"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

That's why you literally get a full URL within a breadcrumb trail.

In fact IDs should be **VERY** consistent domainwise in order to disambiguate entities and actually spare the effort of having to declare one time and another the same thing, like repeating several times a homepage URL or very likely a *postalAdress* if you do content about LocalBusiness and other types of Organization.

A big benefit is that other authors may reference this ID from extrnal sites/domains and even then this will be an univocal relation. Think big, kinda semantic link building (out of scope, just an example of possible use).

You can find a working example in [ZeClinics contact page](http://www.zeclinics.com/contact/) where I am hashing the 2 premises of the company in order to set a precedent to be recalled in future RDF and onpage Schema developments.

Furthermore, if you are using CMS for website maintenance I would perhaps advise to implement Breadcrumb with RDFa (my favorite vs Microdata) and keep this trail apart from the far more flexible (and thus complex) JSON-LD scripts.

This is absolutely common in many WP themes, for example.
Have fun!