# JSON-LD x2 Local Businesses from same Location?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

We are a Private Hire Taxi company but have another company running Countryside Tours from the same address. We have two separate websites.

What would the correct Schema.org JSON-LD structure? Use the Graph object or ParentOrganization object?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use something special at all? Why not simply use an item for the taxi company on the taxi site, and an item for the tour company on the tour site?

Comment: I was thinking that local businesses as specified for the Taxis and Country Tours would be associated with a parent business and therefore make more logical sense? @unor

Comment: So do you have a parent organization? And does it have its own website? Or is one of the two companies the parent?

Comment: The taxi company is the parent and has its own website and so does the Tour company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Without linking them

You could of course simply use a `LocalBusiness` for the taxi company on the taxi site, and a `LocalBusiness` for the tour company on the tour site, without linking them in any way.

```html
<!-- on the taxi site -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "Taxi company",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "Example street 1"
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- on the tour site -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "Tour company",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "Example street 1"
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Linking them

But if you want to convey that the taxi company is the parent company, and the tour company is its child company, you can use the [`parentOrganization`](http://schema.org/parentOrganization)/[`subOrganization`](http://schema.org/subOrganization) properties.

You can do this without repeating the taxi information on the tour site and vice-versa. Simply [give each `LocalBusiness` a URI](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) (via `@id` in JSON-LD) and reference it as the value of the properties.

```html
<!-- on the taxi site -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "@id": "http://taxi.example.com/#company",
  "name": "Taxi company",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "Example street 1"
  },
  "subOrganization": {"@id": "http://tours.example.com/#company"}
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- on the tour site -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "@id": "http://tours.example.com/#company",
  "name": "Tour company",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "Example street 1"
  },
  "parentOrganization": {"@id": "http://taxi.example.com/#company"}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent information. Is one method preferred for SEO purposes? Thank you @unor

Comment: @Barton: Unless a search engine offers a feature that makes use of `parentOrganization`/`subOrganization`, providing or not providing it shouldn’t affect SEO at all.