# Schema.org for artist portfolio website: WebSite, Person or Place type?

Tags: schema.org

A website for an artist has following simple structure:

- index - an image and a very simple description about the artist's work
- blog  - news about the artists projects
- projects - an archive of the realized artist's work
- events - a list of upcoming bookable events
- contact - info about the location of the art studio, email and phone

On the contact page for an artist's website I have:

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Person",
    "additionalName": "Jane Doe",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressCountry": "Country",
        "addressRegion": "Region",
        "postalCode": "1010101",
        "streetAddress": "Address",
        "email": "mail@example.com",
        "telephone": "00123457869"
    },
    "jobTitle": "Artist",
    "image": "http://domain.tld/image-of-artist-768x768.jpg"
}
```

I used the `Person` type on the contact page since I think that is what people would want to find, information about the person and be able to find contact details, no?

Now on the index page I think it would be a good idea to include a property that fits for an art studio. What could such a type or property be?

This is where the artist creates their work but also where at times exhibitions are hosted and the public is invited upon invitation. So most of the time the studio is closed but when there are events taking place the public can visit.

So the what property is best for the index page?
Is this a `WebSite` or a `Person` as well or even an `Organization`?

If the index page has a `Person` type again is this not confusing to search engines to have 2 pages (index and contact) with the same JSON-LD data?

For the projects page I am thinking to use the `CreativeWork` type and for the events the `Event` type.

Comment: Why do you want to use schema.org markup?  The fact that you are asking what type to use indicates that you have no idea who would use it or what the benefits would be.

Comment: What do you want from using schemas? there are a lot of benefits, you need to know what are the benefits and how to do it correctly to achieve those benefits. as @StephenOstermiller mentioned.

Comment: Increase SEO and make the search results appear very structured such as dates of events in rows in under the description of a page? 
Do you want it to be possible from Google to give direct answers when they, for example, search for 'arts created by some_person' to the list of arts created in a structured view? or 'creator of art_something' to show a description of the artist?

To do so, you need to do it correctly. using schemas randomly will just confuse Google which will lead to undesired results.

Comment: There is no general SEO benefit to finding some schema to use.   Schema never changes rankings, it only changes the display of your site in the search results in some cases.  Google has a guide to which schema they use in the search results: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery   If it isn't listed there, it won't do anything to use it.    I don't know of any SEO advantage to implementing any of the schema you mention in your question.   Unless you have a non-SEO reason for it, implementing those is just a waste of time.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller    
Part 1 I read through this https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data and did the tutorial here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/structured-data/index.html and want to enable a rich set of features for the website in search results, so that is the reason I am using schema.org markup and using the JSON-LD format as recommended by Google. Indeed I have an idea who would use the website if that is what you mean.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Part 2 Primarily local users that either know the artist or are in the same country as the artist and like to easily find information about the artist's artwork, bio, news and events. Ideally when searching on Google I like this info to display in an easy digestible way for such interested users, regardless of SEO, what I am not mentioning in my question. The fact that I am asking does not mean that I am clueless, it means that I am trying to find refined information tailored to this use case, an artist's website or e.g. a photographer's portfolio website.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Any info towards how to properly use the JSON-LD format to markup such content would be of invaluable use to me and I guess, countless other people trying to deliver search results for creative websites displayed in a somewhat adjusted per content category case. Thank you.

Comment: @YousefAl-Hadhrami Part 1
Quite simple, I like to enable a rich set of features for the website in search results, meaning I like the search results to display in a way using the features provided by Google so that interested users can find them and also possibly see them displayed in a different layout as seen here https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery
Dates of events in rows under the description of a page sounds excellent, yes!!

Comment: @YousefAl-Hadhrami Part 2 It being possible when searching for arts created by and then showing a list of the arts created by that person as well as showing info when searching for creator of art, well these two use cases would also be tremendously invaluable to implement. Do you know if there is a preview tool for the SERP besides the Google Structured Data Tool and the obvious `site:domian.com/events/` in Google search? And for me to do it correctly, would you mind sharing your info or pointing me to a tutorial or more info where I can read more about how to do this the right way?

Comment: @YousefAl-Hadhrami Part 3 So any sources you could kindly share that touch this use case, searching for art by a person and art created by a person and showing a list of art or bio about the artist, well that would be really highly appreciated. Unfortunately the examples I found so far did not have info tailored to an artist's website, or at least a portfolio website. For example being able to do this for a photographer's site would be excellent. In any case, if you have more sources that will teach me correctly please do kindly share them, thank you. Confusing Google is surly not what I want.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller (answer to your 2nd comment) Part 1
Do you have a factual source to back up you claim that *there is no general SEO benefit to finding some schema to use* and that *Schema never changes rankings*? A source from Google itself would be preferable but anything that shows a before and after and no visible result after implementing Schema in JSON-LD format would be great, thank you. Yes, I saw that guide, thank you for linking that. I also went over the codelabs example, those are already quite helpful, thank you heaps.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller (answer to your 2nd comment) Part 2 Preferably, if nothing else, being able to display the search results in a different way, would already be be one reason, SEO not being the main focus here, more so usability of the search results, tailored to interested parties. So if you also have some sources of information to kindly share where I could obtain proper info to implement this correctly I would be an interested reader of such links/tuts/info. Trying to learn this and while doing so from quality sources, thx.

Comment: https://moz.com/learn/seo/schema-structured-data says: "As of yet, there is no conclusive evidence that this markup improves rankings. But there are some indications that search results with more extensive rich snippets (like those created using Schema) will have a better click-through rate."

Comment: Google likes structured data because it makes websites more machine readable.   Google is providing answers more and more directly from the search results.  Schema is they way the get websites to give them this data.   They have thrown out the bone of rich snippets in exchange for it and many websites have taken them in exchange for vast amounts of machine readable data.  Ultimately Google will get more benefit out of you using schema than you do.

Comment: Interestingly many professional SEO agencies also like schema because it is something they can actually do and their clients can easily see results when rich snippets appear in the search results.   As a result, there is a lot of undeserved hype around schema.

Comment: So my advice is to use schema in cases where that will give you rich snippets.   But you shouldn't use schema unless you know exactly what the benefits are going to be.    Because of the hype, there is a rush to implement schema an everything.  However, you need to be careful because that is giving your data away in ways that you are probably not thinking about.

Comment: I also don't see schema being sustainable for Google to use once it starts getting widely spammed.   I would have thought Google learned its lesson from meta keywords:   You can't trust data that isn't visible to users.   Meta data is easy to fake.  It is tempting to do so when there are no eyeballs on it.   Even Google doesn't have the resources to be the meta data police.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Excellent and elaborate reply, makes a lot of sense, especially the _giving away data_ vs a simple _visual_ benefit that _might_ lead to a better ctr. Also thx for providing the link. Now I am well equipped and know a lot more, not just the syntax but also the pros and cons. Thx!

Answer (score 5):

You can provide multiple entities on each page, and you should do that if it makes sense for the data. The [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) property can be used to convey what the primary entity for this page is.

If you don’t want to repeat the data about an entity on each page, you can define it only on its dedicated page, give it a URI, and reference this URI instead of embedding the full entity ([JSON-LD example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/107407/17633)).

#### Which types to use?

It seems that the artist has a business (as events can be booked), so `LocalBusiness` could be used, or, if it’s not commercial, the parent type `Organization` (if it were a musician, the subtype [`MusicGroup`](https://schema.org/MusicGroup) could be used, even for solo artists).

A homepage which has a business as primary entity, and a person as founder of the business and as author of the homepage, could look like this:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "@id": "",
  "name": "Welcome to Alice Art",

  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "@id": "#org",
    "name": "Alice Art",

    "founder": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "@id": "#me",
      "name": "Alice"
    }

  },

  "publisher": {"@id": "#org"},

  "author": {"@id": "#me"}

}
```

And for a page about a single event, you could have something like this:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "@id": "",

  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "Event",
    "organizer": {"@id": "/#org"},
    "performer": {"@id": "/#me"}
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The guide of Google **[Structured Data General Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)** requires the use of structured data that represent the main content of the website.

- Therefore, if your ***home page (index)*** has the main content representing the artist as a person, then it is useful to use the type **[Person](https://schema.org/Person)**. 
  However, if the main content is the work of the artist, then it may be useful to use the type **[VisualArtwork](https://schema.org/VisualArtwork)**. In both specifications of these types, you can see examples below.
- For the ***blog***, of course, it can be useful to use the type **[Blog](https://schema.org/Blog)** and the type **[BlogPosting](https://schema.org/BlogPosting)** for each of the articles of this blog.
- For the web page ***projects*** the above mentioned type **VisualArtwork** can be useful. However, if the main content of this web page is created as a list, then here you can use the **[guide of Google for Listings](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings)**. Please note that there are **[two ways available for marking the list](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings#guidelines)**:

  - ***Summary page + multiple full details pages***
  - ***A single, all-in-one-page list***
- For the ***Event*** web page it may be useful to use the type **[VisualArtsEvent](https://schema.org/VisualArtsEvent)**. **[Google supports this type](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event)**. There is the property **[performer](https://schema.org/performer)** that can be useful for your artist.
- The choice of the structured data type for the webpage **Contact** again depends on the main content of this webpage. If the artist’s business is represented here, then it may be useful to use the type **[EntertainmentBusiness](https://schema.org/EntertainmentBusiness)**. This type is the more specific type of the **[type LocalBusiness and it is supported by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business)**. If the main content represents a person, then accordingly, the markup for the type **Person** can help here.

Additionally. You can see here that the structured data to some extent helps us in creating the structure of the web pages and the entire website.