# Linking product and offer schema on different pages

Tags: seo, schema.org

I have two pages:

**View Product**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    ....
</div>
```

**View Pricing**

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    ....
</div>
```

Is it possible to somehow make the product point to the pricing page in some way to indicate the prices, or vice versa?

For technical reasons, it's difficult to put the `offers` item props on the product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But that doesn’t necessarily mean that search engines follow these references (they don’t document it).

#### How?

1. Give each item an URI with the `itemid` attribute.
2. Use this URI as value for relevants properties.

You might want to use URIs that represent the thing instead of the page (see the section [Why are identifiers useful?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) in my answer).

#### Example

So on the product page, you could have:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemid="/products/42#this">
  <link itemprop="offers" href="/offers/42#this" />
</div>
```

And on the offer page, you could have:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemid="/offers/42#this">
  <link itemprop="itemOffered" href="/products/42#this" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is there evidence that search engines like Google and Bing can follow link references like that? Depending on the item being linked, Google's Structured Data Testing Tool will complain about missing data.

Comment: @Dave: The SDTT doesn’t support it, but of course that doesn’t necessarily mean that Google doesn’t support it. I guess it makes sense that the tool doesn’t follow references, because there could be many, possibly endless, even to external documents. -- My guess (I have no evidence, just a guess) is that the Googlebot will follow those references (these are, after all, normal `a`/`area`/`link` hyperlinks), but without "adding" the structured data from the linked page to the linking page.