# Schema.org Microdata Across Multiple Pages

Tags: schema.org, microdata

Say I have markup like this on `https://example.org/index.html`:

```html
<span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://example.org/index.html">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Example Industries">
    <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="CA">
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="ON">
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Ottawa">
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="telephone" content="613-555-1234">
    ...
</span>
```

Then on `https://example.org/employees/joe-blow.html` I have

```html
<span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://example.org/employees/joe-blow.html">
    <meta itemprop="givenName" content="Joe">
    <meta itemprop="familyName" content="Blow">
    <span itemprop="worksFor" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        <meta itemprop="url" content="https://example.org/index.html">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Example Industries">
    </span>
</span>
```

I obviously don't want to repeat all the information about the `LocalBusiness` within each `Person`. Is this a valid way for the `Person` to reference the `LocalBusiness` on another page?

---

I've also tried it like this:

`https://example.org/index.html`:

```html
<span itemid="#business" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://example.org/index.html">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Example Industries">
    <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="CA">
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="ON">
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Ottawa">
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="telephone" content="613-555-1234">
    ...
</span>
```

`https://example.org/employees/joe-blow.html`:

```html
<span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://example.org/employees/joe-blow.html">
    <meta itemprop="givenName" content="Joe">
    <meta itemprop="familyName" content="Blow">
    <link itemprop="worksFor" href="https://example.org/#business">
</span>
```

But Google's validator doesn't seem to recognize the linked information. It complained unless I re-included the `name` property of the `LocalBusiness`.

Comment: Side note: You must use `link` with `href` attribute (instead of `meta` with `content` attribute) if the value is a URL, e.g., for your `url` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to reference/link with Microdata and Schema.org

If possible, I would use both ways (`url` property from Schema.org & `itemid` attribute from Microdata).

While Schema.org isn’t that strict about it, I think it makes sense to use different URIs for them, if you want to [differentiate between the page and the thing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633):

- Schema.org’s `url` property gives the URI of the page about the thing.
- Microdata’s `itemid` attribute gives the URI of the thing.

For example, the URI `https://example.org/employees/joe-blow.html` points to a page about Joe Blow, and the URI `https://example.org/employees/joe-blow.html#i` is the URI for Joe Blow himself. Then you could specify:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemid="/employees/joe-blow.html#i">
  <link itemprop="url" href="/employees/joe-blow.html" />
</div>
```

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AboutPage" itemid="/employees/joe-blow.html">
  <link itemprop="about mainEntity" href="/employees/joe-blow.html#i" />
  <!-- just for the sake of the example; you would typically include the 'Person' item here -->
</div>
```

#### Search engine support

Google’s SDTT doesn’t follow links. Copying [my comment to a related question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104018/linking-product-and-offer-schema-on-different-pages/104021?noredirect=1#comment131875_104021):

> The SDTT doesn’t support it, but of course that doesn’t necessarily mean that Google doesn’t support it. I guess it makes sense that the tool doesn’t follow references, because there could be many, possibly endless, even to external documents. -- My guess (I have no evidence, just a guess) is that the Googlebot will follow those references (these are, after all, normal `a`/`area`/`link` hyperlinks), but without "adding" the structured data from the linked page to the linking page.

As far as I know, no search engine documents that they would follow references in structured data to do something with it.