# How to tell search engine that 'this website/this businss/ is the item being reviewed?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

I want my client reviews, on my own site, to be in review scheme - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#review-snippets

I have to include `itemReviewed` and I guess I should make it a `LocalBusiness`.

Are there particular attributes and values of those attributes that I should use, for `LocalBusiness`, to tell Google that the item being reveiwed is 'this business, who's site your looking at now'.

I can see a `sameAs` attributes who's value I can set to a URL which I could set to the website's URL. Is that a good way to do it or should I do it some other way?

Answer (score 1):

As far as Google’s rich results are concerned, you find every supported property in the documentation you linked. What you ask about doesn’t seem to be related to the review rich result itself, as Google doesn’t need to make a difference in case the reviewed business is (or is not) the owner of the page. So as far as Google is concerned, we are entering undocumented territory: it’s not clear wich method Google recognizes (or if any at all).

You could do the following:

1. Provide a [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) item.
2. Specify your `LocalBusiness` as [`author`](http://schema.org/author)/[`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher)/etc. of that `WebPage`. (Check which of the properties that take an `Organization` item as value apply in your case.)
3. If the page with the reviews is only about your business: Specify your `LocalBusiness` as value for the [`about`](http://schema.org/about) property of the `WebPage`.
4. And in the reviews, specify this `LocalBusiness` as value for the `itemReviewed` properties, too.

That way, interested consumers can learn that this `LocalBusiness` is [1.] responsible for the current page as well as [2.] the target of the reviews.

Depending on your markup, it might not be possible for you to specify your `LocalBusiness` exactly once. In that case, [identifiers (`@id`, `itemid`, `resource`)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) could help (not only in this case, it’s generally a good idea to provide them).

Comment: You are one if the very few users that I can up vote without reading the answer. I always read them after the fact!

Comment: @closetnoc: Thank you, closetnoc! But I would appreciate if you vote *after* reading, and always consider to use the other vote button, too -- I most certainly have published several answers that would warrant downvotes :)

Comment: I actually do read them, then vote. However I am not sure why. We all drop little stinkers here and there. I prefer not to down vote without the poster having an opportunity to fix the Q or A. Then again some answers are just plain dangerous. You  have expertise than can be trusted and I can really appreciate it. Cheers!!