# Can two Product schema.org elements be combined with an @id attribute?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, json-ld

Supposing I have a product detail page on my shopping website where 2 seperate schema.org [`Product` elements](https://schema.org/Product) have been defined with JSON-LD:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Product","name":"Modern Cotton Thong",
    "aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":"4.84",
    "reviewCount":"43"}
  }  
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Product","name":"Modern Cotton Thong",
    "price": 20.0,
    "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock"
  }   
</script>
```

As you can see one of these has `aggregateRating` data and the other has `price` and `availability` information. Now let's assume there is no way to combine these into one element (because they came from different vendors).

One problem we are facing is when Google reads this, it is only picking up one and not the other. For example, our page will have price and availability but it will not have the stars and rating which come from `AggregateRating` on organic SERP.

Would it be possible to combine these two elements with an `@id` attribute?

Comment: Yes. The Structured Data Testing Tool can confirm that for you.

Comment: See also: [Duplicate schema/structured data markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48532381/1591669) and [What is the use of @id in json-ld syntax?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/98569/17633)

Comment: @TonyMcCreath, thanks for confirming that. Could you also offer any suggestions as to the value of said id attribute? Can it be some arbitrary string or the SKU of the product or a URL of some kind?

Comment: I believe it has to be a valid Uri. I'm not sure if it has to relate to an existing page, but I think that would be beneficial. People often use the URL for the page the entity is formally defined on, and sometimes add a hash value to differentiate multiple entities on the one page. e.g. #Product would work for the official Product entity on the current page.