# JSON-LD problem with non-Latin characters: Product appears as last item of BreadcrumbList

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I spent two days to find out what the problem is with the following JSON-LD, but to no avail.

If you check this code in testing tool, you will see `Product` weirdly appears as the last item of `BreadcrumbList`.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org\/","@graph":
[{"@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"name":"teest","@id":"https:\/\/tennisfa.com\/shop"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"name":"test","@id":"https:\/\/tennisfa.com\/shop\/product-category\/3\/"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"item":{"name":"test","@id":"https://tennisfa.com/shop/product/%d8%b3%d8%a7%da%a9-%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3-%d9%87%d8%af-tour-team-wimbledon-12r-monstercombi/"}}]},{"@type":"Product","@id":"https://tennisfa.com/shop/product/%d8%b3%d8%a7%da%a9-%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3-%d9%87%d8%af-tour-team-wimbledon-12r-monstercombi/","name":" Tour Team Wimbledon 12R Monstercombi","image":"https:\/\/tennisfa.com\/shop\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/11\/htourteamwimbledon12r.jpg","description":"test","sku":"283108","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","price":"1550000","priceSpecification":{"price":"1550000","priceCurrency":"IRT","valueAddedTaxIncluded":"false"},"priceCurrency":"IRT","availability":"https://tennisfa.com/shop/product/%d8%b3%d8%a7%da%a9-%d8%aa%d9%86%db%8c%d8%b3-%d9%87%d8%af-tour-team-wimbledon-12r-monstercombi/","seller":   {"@type":"Organization","name":"test","url":"https:\/\/tennisfa.com\/shop"}}]}]}
</script>
```

I think the problem is with the non-latin URLs. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third `ListItem` and the `Product` have the same URI (in `@id`).¹ This means they are the same thing.

If the structure allows it (like in your case), Google’s SDTT displays an item only once, even if it’s defined in different JSON objects.

#### URIs for page vs. product

If you care about Linked Data, there is one thing you might want to consider: The webpage and the product (which this webpage is about) are different things, so they [should have different URIs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633):

- the `ListItem`’s `item` would be the [`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage) (instead of the `Product`), because breadcrumbs link to pages, not to things described on these pages
- the `ItemPage` has the canonical URL of the page as `@id`
- the `Product` has the canonical URL of the page + a fragment identifier (e.g., `#product`) as `@id`

By using `ItemPage`, you can also make use of the [`breadcrumb`](https://schema.org/breadcrumb) and [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) properties, so you no longer need to have unrelated top-level objects in `@graph`.

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ItemPage",
  "@id": ""
  "breadcrumb": {
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList"
  },
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "Product"
    "@id": "#product"
  }
}
```

---

¹ By the way, the `availability` property has this URI, too, but this is most likely an error.

Answer (score 0):

The **[specification of the property **availability](https://schema.org/availability)**** tells us:

> The availability of this item—for example In stock, Out of stock, Pre-order, etc.

and

> Values expected to be one of these types ItemAvailability

The Enumeration members of the type **[ItemAvailability](https://schema.org/ItemAvailability)**:

> Discontinued
>
> InStock
>
> InStoreOnly
>
> LimitedAvailability
>
> OnlineOnly
>
> OutOfStock
>
> PreOrder
>
> PreSale
>
> SoldOut

It may be useful to use these values for the property availability but not url as you have it.