# Should Website and Organization be linked?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

I'm wondering what the effects/benefits/issues are with linking `Website` and `Organization` structured data (specifically in JSON-LD).

On the homepage of my site I have something like this:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
[{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"Organization",
    "@id":"https://example.com/",
    "url":"http://example.com",
    "name":"My site",
    "logo":"https://example.com/logo.jpg",
    "sameAs": [
        "https://www.facebook.com/example/",
        "https://twitter.com/example"
    ]},
    {
        "@context":"http://schema.org",
        "@type":"WebSite",
        "@id":"https://example.com/",
        "url":"https://example.com",
        "name":"My Site",
        "potentialAction":{
            "@type":"SearchAction",
            "target":"https://example.com?searchQuery={search_term_string}",
            "query-input":"required name=search_term_string"
        }
}]
</script>
```

In this case I've connected the `Website` and `Organization` with the same ID. I've noticed in the [Structured Data Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), Google will combine this into one data type:

[image: Screenshot of Structured Data Testing results]

I'm using `Website` for the potential benefits of the site search box and I'm using `Organization` for the benefits of contact point and linking to social accounts.

My question is: is this a good idea? Is there any reason to not connect these two items in structured data? What implications are there to link these items vs. keeping them as separate IDs?

Comment: Why do you want to give them the same `@id`?

Comment: @unor - I think that's mainly my question - is there a reason I shouldn't link these via ID and keep them separate? What are the implications?

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294593/how-do-you-combine-several-json-ld-markups @unor has explained it perfectly, you can combine multiple schema without having separate file for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Same `@id`?

If items have the same `@id`, they *are* the same. These two snippets are semantically equivalent:

```json
[
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "@id": "https://example.com/"
  },
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "@id": "https://example.com/"
  }
]
```

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": ["Organization", "WebSite"],
  "@id": "https://example.com/"
}
```

But are the organization and its website the same thing? I would say no. Examples that show why these are different entities:

- Others might want to make statements *only* about the website or *only* about the organization. For example, if someone states `<#i> ex:likes <https://example.com/> .`, maybe they actually only like the website, but not the organization. If both were the same, it wouldn’t be possible to differentiate.
- An organization might have multiple websites (e.g., per language), but if the organization and all of its websites would be the same entity, it would not be possible to associate the different [`url`](https://schema.org/url) values with the corresponding [`inLanguage`](https://schema.org/inLanguage) values. Each language version should get its own `WebSite` item ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46772356/1591669)).

#### A different `@id` for each thing

[I would recommend](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) to give your `Organization` its own `@id`, for example:

```json
{
  "@type": "Organization",
  "@id": "https://example.com/#org",
  "url": "https://example.com/"
}
```

If you want to [go the extra mile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099116/1591669), you could even give your `WebSite` its own `@id`, so that it can be differentiated from the homepage:

```json
{
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "@id": "https://example.com/#site",
  "url": "https://example.com/"
}
```

```json
{
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "@id": "https://example.com/",
  "url": "https://example.com/"
}
```

#### Linking `Organization` and `WebSite`

You can associate the organization and its website(s) with suitable properties like [`author`](https://schema.org/author)/[`creator`](https://schema.org/creator), [`copyrightHolder`](https://schema.org/copyrightHolder), and/or [`publisher`](https://schema.org/publisher), as well as [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity)/[`about`](https://schema.org/about).

([JSON-LD example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43917881/1591669))

Comment: @unor (related to the last paragraph) For an online seller, is the property `provider` more appropriate (than `publisher`) to connect these 2 relations a) `WebSite` with `Organization`, and b) page (`ItemPage`/`CollectionPage`/...) with `Organization`?

Comment: @EthanCollins: If both properties make sense, I would use both.