# When referencing an entity from another page, should only @id and @type be specified, or should all necessary attributes be duplicated?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, semantic-web

I have multiple web pages in my website; "about" page (e.g.: `http://example.com/about/`) and "blog" pages (e.g.: `http//:example.com/blog/1/`).

In the "about" page, I have defined authors of the website. Each author has given a proper `@id` attribute.

Articles of the blog pages are written by someone from that author list in the "about" page. When I'm specifying the author of an article in a "blog" page, what should I do?

```json
"author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "http://example.com/about/#user1"
}
```

1. Specify the author with only the above information (is `@type` really needed here?)
2. Specify all the necessary attributes of the author (duplicate the item from "about" page)

Comment: There is no need to use schema for authorship anymore, Google isn't giving a rich snippet based on authorship now.

Comment: Also I think that the way it was used by Google, you had to have one page per author.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, @AlexisWilke, in a case where there are book pages and a library page where I have links to those books, what should I do? Use only `@id` for a book in the library page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, it’s sufficient to specify only the `@id`:

```json
"author": {"@id": "http://example.com/about/#bob"}
```

If a consumer already knows the entity with this `@id` URI (e.g., after having crawled the "about" page), they don’t need to see its properties here again.
If a consumer doesn’t already know the entity with this URI, they have the chance to learn more about it by visiting the URL and looking for an entity with the `@id` URI.

In practice, however, consumers don’t necessarily 1) remember which entities they found, and/or 2) visit referenced URLs. For example, if the consumer is a search engine, they *might* only care about what’s on the current page (e.g., because they want to display a rich result for it), ignoring every reference to other pages for this context.

So, it can be good idea to provide more data about a referenced entity.

If you know that a consumer expects certain properties on the current page, you should of course provide (at least) these. For example, Google’s Article rich result for AMP pages [requires](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article?hl=en#article_types) the type and `name` of an author.

If you don’t know what possible consumers expect, I think it makes sense to always provide at least the URI (`@id`) and type (`@type`) as well as the Schema.org properties `name` and `url`.

```json
"author": {
  "@type": "Person",
  "@id": "http://example.com/about/#bob",
  "url": "http://example.com/about/#author-bob",
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

(`@id` and `url` have different values, [because](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) `@id` represents the actual person, while `url` represents the page (or page section) about this person.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. nice explanation.
I have seen your answers in here and stackoverflow. Those are nice and well structured like a tutorial. Thank you again!!